# How to send data from UITableViewCell to ViewController in Swift 5

Tags: uitableview, swift5

I have one UISlider and one UILabel. I want to reflect the value from that UISlider to my UILabel.
I have a UITableViewCell where I have both outlets and I have a ViewController where I connected the Slider and I create an action function (ValueChanged). I did the logic in that function but is not working because is saying that my outlet is NIL.
Can anyone help me to pass this data correctly ? 
Maybe can be done with Delegates but I don't know how more exactly.

Here is my code for UITableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class SliderCell: UITableViewCell {

    // Interface Links
    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

And here is the Controller:

```
import UIKit

// Table View with Dynamic Cells
class MainViewController: UITableViewController {

    var sliderCell: SliderCell!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sliderCell = SliderCell()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        switch indexPath.row {
        // Row 0  -  My Slider
        case 0:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sliderCell", for: indexPath) as! SliderCell
            return cell
        default:
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        // Set the height for slider cell to 200 pixels
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            return 200
        default:
            return 200
        }
    }

    // Reflect the value of Slider to ProgressLabel
    @IBAction func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {

        var currentValue = Int(sender.value)
        let stepSize:Int = 10
        currentValue = (currentValue - currentValue % stepSize)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.sliderCell.progressLabel.text = "\(currentValue)%"
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance if you are reading this !

Comment: If the table view will contain only one cell why don't you use a **static** cell with outlets  (or why do you use a table view at all? )

Comment: Because my project have 20 cells which need to be hidden in different situations.
This is just a simple example for what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add a reference to your cell here

```
sliderCell = SliderCell()
```

but use  a delegate in cellForRowAt like

```
  let cell = 
  cell.delegate = self
```

then inside the cell send anything with

```
delegate?.sendSliderValue()
```

you can also add slider action implementation inside the vc like

```
let cell = //
cell.slider.addTarget ////
cell.slider.tag = indexPath.row

 @objc func sliderChanged(_ slider:UISlider) { 
     print(slider.value,slider.tag)
     if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at:IndexPath(row:slider.tag,section:0)) as? SliderCell {
         var currentValue = Int(sender.value)
         let stepSize:Int = 10
         currentValue = (currentValue - currentValue % stepSize)
         cell.progressLabel.text = "\(currentValue)"
     }

     // or 

     if let cell = tableView.visibleCells.first as? SliderCell {
       //////
     }
 }
```

Comment: The second example with AddTarget works for me. The example with Delegate I wasn't able to implement it.
Now how can I reflect the value of the slider on the UILabel which is in the UITableViewCell ?
Thanks Sh_Khan !

Comment: I managed to do it with Delegate and Protocol ! I'm so happy ! :D
Thanks !